# localization in 2-categories with 2-morphisms

Tags: category-theory, localization, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

I know almost nothing about higher categories. In a 2-category, is there a way to localize on a set of 2-morphisms rather than 1-morphisms ?

Comment: I see know reason why you shouldn't be able to take the underlying globular set of the 2 category, add symbols for the inverses, take the free 2 category on the resulting globular set and quotient by the least amount of equations that you need so that the equations of the original 2 category hold and so that the inverses are inverses.